# How to export Wordpress posts, comments, pages and media files ONLY?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have this website - www.spieltimes.com

Now, I'm willing to restart the entire website from scratch, including databases and cPanel.

So, I just want to back up my posts, pages, comments and images. Rest, I don't think are too relevant.

Is there any way to export/import only the posts, pages, comments and images(including featured ones)?

Comment: you could download the `uploads` folder, and export the `wp_post` and `wp_postmeta` tables etc and import them again.

Comment: I've downloaded the uploads folder, wp_post and wp_postmeta tables. Is there anything left, or should I import only these three?

Comment: you might want users as well-

Comment: and remember to regenerate you permalinks on the new site

Comment: how is this a python question exactly ??? (tag removed)

Comment: Actually, how is this a programming question at all ?

Comment: Note that WP stores the contents with bbcode markup, which most of the time can only be interpreted by your exact WP install (plugins etc), so just getting the raw contents from the database is not going to get you very far...

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can export your WordPress site. Some of the easiest ways are-

- Use built-in export tools
- Export site from WordPress.com
- Use plugins

**Built in Export Tools**
WordPress has their own built in export tools to export your site. To use that tools you need to login to your website and then go to **Tools > Export**

Now from the Choose what to export option select all contents.It will export all of your website contents including pages. posts, menus, tags, sidebar, widgets everything you have in your website. It will export your database but this method won’t help you to export your theme file and plugins.

Click on the Download Export File button and your website databases will be exported in .xml file format.

From this built in tools you not only export website but also import that database in a new site. For this you need to go to your new site and login to WordPress dashboard. After that go to **Tools > Import**.

This is the default import tools for WordPress website. Here you will be able to see a option named WordPress importer. At first you need to install it.

After installing it you can see the run importer option. To import your website just click on the run importer option.

It will open up a new window and in the Choose file option you can select your file or drop your file there then click on the Upload file and import button.

Following this step you can easily export your website database and import it into a new website.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress stores all this in an sql database. You could use this same database and develop your app on top, or you could export the data to another database by writing a python script (or any other) that reads data from the database and writes them to another database. 
For images, only the paths are stored in the database.

See for example https://pypi.org/project/python-sql/

Comment: I'm not from the coding field. Could you help me out?

Comment: Wordpress doesn't store images in the database so you have to deal with the filesystem too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WordPress then you should use https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/ plugin. It is the best plugin for export and import the data.

I have tested this `All-in-One WP migration` plugin. Hope it will work you also.

As you are not from the coding background, so it will be helpful for you. Just install the plugin export/import data.